# Power BI - Filtro de fechas inicial y final

Tags: powerbi, filtro

Tengo un Dashboard con Actividades que tienen una fecha inicial y final (Línea de tiempo).

Necesito tener un filtro que me controle las fechas y muestre en los distintos gráficos, las actividades hasta su fecha final. Es decir, Actividad 1, fecha inicial 02/03/20 y fecha final 05/04/20.

Cuando seleccione Enero, no deberá aparecer registro, si seleccionó Febrero, no deberá traer registro, pero si en Marzo y Abril.

Tengo un filtro con el mes, pero solo me funciona con la fecha inicial y no así hasta la fecha final.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Tienes una tabla de Actividades, otra tabla con las fechas y una relación entre las dos tablas?

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por atender mi solicitud. Tienes una tabla de Actividades, otra tabla con las fechas y una relación entre las dos tablas? Sí,

Tengo la tabla de Actividades(Datos) con la siguiente información:

```
Producto, Evento,   Fecha inicial, Fecha final, Responsable
 1a       prueba 1  01/02/2020     29/09/2020   Ana Laura 
 1a       prueba 2  21/09/2020     01/10/2020   Agustin
 2a       prueba 3  01/01/2020     05/05/2020   Romina
 3a       prueba 4  01/02/2020     01/02/2020   Esther
```

Quisiera que al seleccionar una fecha por ejemplo 29/09/2020 me arroje como resultado todas las actividades que caen en esa fecha(Ya sea fecha inicial o final):

En este caso, tomando como referencia los datos de ejemplo,  como resultado debería arrojarme:

```
Producto, Evento,   Fecha inicial, Fecha final, Responsable  
 1a       prueba 1  01/02/2020     29/09/2020   Ana Laura    
 1a       prueba 2  21/09/2020     01/10/2020   Agustin
```

El resultado me daría la visibilidad de las actividades a realizar en el día seleccionado.

También requiero que esos resultados que se arrojen sean tomados en todos los gráficos que utilice.

Comment: No entiendo ¿esto es una respuesta?